# ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS over a cursor?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11.5

Before I realized that there existed a procedure for revalidating objects (SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS), I wrote my own. Now, I try to replace that with the standard one, but it appears as if the call to SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS destroys the cursor I'm looping over. Example of old procedure:

```
db2 -td@ +c "BEGIN FOR v AS c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT SCHEMANAME FROM NYA.VALIDATION_SCHEMAS DO CALL TOOLBOX.COMPILE_SCHEMA2(v.schemaname); END FOR; END @"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Example using ADMISN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS

```
db2 "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS(object_schema=>'TMP')"
Return Status = 0
db2 "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS(object_schema=>'TMP')"
Return Status = 0
```

Trying to use that in a loop over a cursor:

```
db2 -td@ +c "BEGIN FOR v AS c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT SCHEMANAME FROM NYA.VALIDATION_SCHEMAS DO CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS(object_schema=>v.schemaname); END FOR; END @"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0501N  The cursor specified in a FETCH statement or CLOSE statement is not 
open or a cursor variable in a cursor scalar function reference is not open.  
SQLSTATE=24501
```

Note that it does not help to hard wire the schema:

```
db2 -td@ +c "BEGIN FOR v AS c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT SCHEMANAME FROM NYA.VALIDATION_SCHEMAS DO CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS(object_schema=>'TMP')
[...]
```

also yields an error. I tried variations on looping over a cursor:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE v_at_end INTEGER default 0;
    DECLARE not_found CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR for
        SELECT SCHEMANAME FROM NYA.VALIDATION_SCHEMAS;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not_found  SET v_at_end = 1 ;

    OPEN C1;
    fetch_loop:
    LOOP
        FETCH FROM C1 INTO s;
        IF v_at_end <>0 THEN LEAVE fetch_loop; END IF;
        CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS(object_schema=>s);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C1;
END
@
```

But it does not work either. Any clue, what needs to be done to be able to call ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS in a loop?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use a `with hold` cursor? Check if the called sproc does a commit either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: WITH HOLD seems to solve this issue, if you add an answer I'll accept it (If you don't I can add it myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To ensure consistency of catalogs data, the `ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS` routine is designed to run explicit `COMMIT` statements.

Therefore, the cursor must be declared `WITH HOLD` for it to remain valid across commits.